# how to connect with a mongodb running in a container on aws ec2 from my home?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I run a container with the oficial mongo image https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

Here my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:   
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo-integrator
    restart: always
    env_file: prod.env
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ../mongo/data/db:/data/db
      - ../mongo/custom-conf:/etc/custom-conf
    command: --config /etc/custom-conf/mongod.conf
```

Here my mongod.conf file:

```
net:
   bindIpAll: true
```

aws security group:

```
Custom TCP  TCP 27017   0.0.0.0/0   –
Custom TCP  TCP 27017   ::/0    –
```

I've had success on connect with mongodb from another docker-compose service, but I can't connect from my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just was my anti virus (Malwarebytes).

So, the answer: verify and disable your anti virus software